# Share Plus doesnt work on TestFlight ios app flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using share_plus 4.0.10 to share a simple string of code and it works within an android emulator. However, upon posting the app to testflight for beta testing, the share button doesn't seem to work. It only shows airdrop as a share option, and pressing airdrop does nothing.The code is pretty simple.
onPressed: () {
Share.share('id',subject:'...')}

Comment: Did you add url schemes too?

Comment: What are url schemes?

Comment: In which device ,have you tested in ipad or iphone?

Comment: In info.plist you may have to add url schemes

Comment: I used an iPhone

Comment: Is there a way to do that from a windows computer?

Answer (score 2):

share_plus requires iPad users to provide the sharePositionOrigin parameter.

Without it, share_plus will not work on iPads and may cause a crash or letting the UI not responding.

To avoid that problem, provide the sharePositionOrigin.

```
For example:

    
    // Use Builder to get the widget context
Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => _onShare(context),
          child: const Text('Share'),
     );
  },
),

// _onShare method:
final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

await Share.share(
  text,
  subject: subject,
  sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
);
```

See the main.dart in the example for a complete example.

Comment: Don't ignore the `Builder` I repeat don't ignore the `Builder`...

Comment: Yup, ignored builder didnt work lol. Added builder, worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did not understand quite well how the sharePositionOrigin works on the Ipad but I did it like this:

```
await Share.share(
 user.name,
 sharePositionOrigin: Rect.fromPoints(
    const Offset(2, 2), const Offset(3, 3)));
```

This pops the share dialog on the top left corner. Still have to play with this but it is not a core issue for my app, so will get back to it later. Hope this helps though.